# How to build create-react-app so client can't see code in an organized way

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm using create react-app and noticed that with my builds the client can see my exact code as I see it when I'm editing. I would like to prevent this to (at least a little bit) deter clients from easily cheating in my game. If they can see how everything works that easily, they will be more likely to alter the client code. When I go to Facebook.com which uses React, I see that in Chrome source inspector I can't access the clean neat files, just a bunch of code jammed together. How can I achieve this with create-react-app? Also, how can I remove the comments before I build? I assumed, when I built this would happen, because why would the client need to see your comments, but it does not.

Comment: I think *[that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49123885/when-does-create-react-app-obfuscate-or-minify-code)* might be related. Check the `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP` env

Comment: use the production build. `create-react-app` has a `build` command that kicks off the prod build (aka `yarn build` or `npm run build`). That minifies the code so you have small bundle files to download on production websites. Code minifying gives you the effect of "*a bunch of code jammed together*"

Comment: Ramiz, that seems like it did the trick. If I remove the .map will that also get rid of all comments? There will be no possible way for the client to decipher my comments? Or do I need to use some third-party module to remove them before the build?

Answer (score 2):

When you run react in the development mode using the create-react-app, the source code is not optimized for production. It offers more development purposes. 
You need to run *yarn build* to get the optimized version which will be minified and uglified as you like which will give you some amount of code hiding ability.