# How to uglify production code in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, uglifyjs

Correction made to my previous Question (Instead of<strike>Obfuscate</strike>, I'm actually trying to find out **Uglify**)

I've recently began to work on ReactJS, while I try to bundle to code in production.. I realized all the codes are in readable format. I'm aware of the approach below:
[Set false to generate sourcemap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51287726/4311268).

However, this way my code is still kind of readable in terms of my

1. API Endpoint
2. API keys

I'm trying to understand what is the proper way to fully **uglify** my code in production?

Comment: You can't obfuscate API endpoint and keys. They're designed to be public.

Comment: Even if code was completely hidden (which is impossible because it needs to run on the client), you could still open network tab and see all the information there.

Comment: You can't. Anything you send to the client will be visible.

Comment: adding to the chorus, things on your client have to be safely public.

Comment: My guess is that you are getting downvotes because people here don't like obfuscated code. It is still a valid question, however.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Well, understand the endpoints will still be revealed via network tab, that was just an example. I do see some react website has their code fully convert to unreadable format. Im curious to find out how that works. I don't find this an invalid question, please don't vote down / close? Help to explain and leave an answer to the rest will be helpful. (:

Comment: You can actually do so manually. Just use constants and put jibberish in there. Then, when you're accessing the endpoint you can just use the constant instead of a string. That way you keep the endpoints consistent without exposing the human-understandable strings in the API.

Comment: Correction made to my question.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how we can UGLIFY our code in ReactJS.

1. Run `npm run eject`
2. Run `npm install uglifyjs-webpack-plugin --save-dev`
3. Go to webpack.config.js at your config folder (you should get this folder after eject)
4. Search for keyword `minimize: isEnvProduction` then append the following at bottom

```
minimizer: [
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
          uglifyOptions: {
            warnings: false,
            parse: {},
            compress: {},
            mangle: true, // Note `mangle.properties` is `false` by default.
            output: null,
            toplevel: false,
            nameCache: null,
            ie8: false,
            keep_fnames: false,
          },
        }),
      ],
```

If you now build your app `npm run build` for production environment, and you shall not see your code via Inspect Element.

Comment: you should edit the original question if you're providing the additional information

Comment: Yes, I've actually edited the question. Earlier I was asking about obfuscation, but I'm actually looking for solution to uglify. Which is why I try to bold the word uglify now to all readers.

Comment: ah, okay, got it :D