# GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false, but source code is still generated

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-scripts

I want to hide the ReactJS source code from the production.
So searching after some info the web lead me to the simple solution of adding

```
set  GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false && react-scripts build
```

to the build configuration file. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51415780/create-react-app-is-showing-all-my-code-in-production-how-to-hide-it/51415855#51415855) for example.

But after doing that, the source code is still generated. Although the option is set. I use Windows.

Does someone have an idea why it happens?

I have tried also to do it from the win-cmd (and not from WebStorm terminal) and to use build --nomaps option. But it didn't help.

[image: Config-file.]

[image: npm-logs]

[image: maps-files-still-exist]

Answer (score 1):

I found out the solution, and share it here for those who will encounter this issue.

Because it's on windows you have to add **double** quotes to this command (and not single like I did):

```
"build": "set \"GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false\" && react-scripts build",
```

After adding it, it's working.

[image: Map now not exist]

Credit to [this article that says it on Answers 5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49123885/).

[Here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8340) is a similar issue .